# Numdifftools to calculate lmfit fit uncertainties

Tags: python, ode, data-fitting, lmfit

I'm using lmfit to estimate the parameters of a coupled ODE system, based on thus example: https://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/sta-663/CalibratingODEs.html.
In order to obtain a global minimal of the residual I switched to use either the "basinhopping" or "ampgo" methods, but I get such warning when displaying the results:

```
Warning: uncertainties could not be estimated:
this fitting method does not natively calculate uncertainties
and numdifftools is not installed for lmfit to do this.  Use
`pip install numdifftools` for lmfit to estimate uncertainties
with this fitting method.
```

I have installed "numdifftools" via conda, but the warning (and the lack of uncertainties) persists.
How can I solve this?

Here is the code with minimal data:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from lmfit import minimize, Parameters, Parameter, report_fit
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def f(xs, t, ps):

    Ksor = ps['Ksor'].value
    Kdes = ps['Kdes'].value

    Cw, Cs, SS = xs

    return [-Ksor*SS*Cw+Kdes*Cs, Ksor*SS*Cw-Kdes*Cs,0]

def g(t, x0, ps):
    """
    Solution to the ODE x'(t) = f(t,x,k) with initial condition x(0) = x0
    """
    x = odeint(f, x0, t, args=(ps,))
    return x

def residual(ps, ts, data):
    x0 = ps['Cw0'].value, ps['Cs0'].value, ps['SS0'].value
    model = g(ts, x0, ps)
    return (model - data).ravel()

data1=np.array([[100.    ,   0.    ,   1.    ],
   [ 66.5507,  33.4493,   1.    ],
   [ 44.4018,  55.5982,   1.    ],
   [ 29.7357,  70.2643,   1.    ]])

t = pd.Series([0.408,0.816,1.224,1.632])
x0 = np.array([100,0,1])

# set parameters incluing bounds
params = Parameters()
params.add('Cw0', value=100, vary=False)
params.add('Cs0', value=0, vary=False)
params.add('SS0', value=1, vary=False)
params.add('Ksor', value=2.0, min=0, max=100)
params.add('Kdes', value=1.0, min=0, max=100)


# fit model and find predicted values
result = minimize(residual, params, args=(t, data1), method='basinhopping')
final = data1 + result.residual.reshape(data1.shape)

# plot data and fitted curves
plt.plot(t, data1, 'o')
plt.plot(t, final, '-', linewidth=2);

# display fitted statistics
report_fit(result)
```

EDIT: the code works. I think that the installation of numdifftools wasn't detected and a restart of the PC solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is always helpful to provide a minimal but complete example that shows the problem and the result (including fit report and/or any exceptions) that you get.  Please modify the question to include these and give the version of lmfit and numdifftools you are using.

Also: The use of numdifftools to calculate the uncertainties requires the length of the residual array to be larger than the number of variables.

Comment: ... but you did not give the version of lmfit or numdifftools or the full output you got. ;) Your example works for me (lmfit 0.9.13, numdifftools 0.9.39, python 3.7.3).  FWIW, I would suggest trying `method='leastsq'` first -- it should get you very close with 4000x fewer function calls.  `method='ampgo'` might also be useful as a global optimizer.

Comment: It works for me as well. I think that the installation of numdifftools wasn't detected and that's why it kept asking to install it. Thanks anyway for your help and the other optimizers